# Setting a global value (and keeping it) within the scope of an eval

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a large Rails 5 app (Ruby 2.6.x at present) that makes crucial use of `Kernel::eval` (please don't tell me to try to refactor this out because eval is dangerous - I didn't write the original code, and this is not in the cards for any time soon).

There are a very wide variety of Ruby expressions (coming out of the db) that can be passed to eval, sometimes of great complexity, making extensive use of classes and resources of the app.

(you might want to jump straight down to BIG EDIT below)

**What I want is to be able to set a global value (`$global`) that will be seen within the scope of the eval execution, but that will not "infect" any of the execution context outside of that.** I can't try to interpolate this into the string and pass it down though method params and such, because, as I say, the code being eval'ed is complex and stacks can get very deep, and I want the value to potentially be accessed (though never modified) anywhere within.

I understand about Bindings. I have played around with setting local and instance vars in a binding, and passing this to eval, but inevitably these are not seen inside any method calls within the eval, especially if I'm inside a method of some random class (which I always am). Seems like global is the only possibility. But experimentation shows that a global set inside an eval remains in the code that calls the eval:

```rb
2.6.3 :002 > $foo
 => nil 
2.6.3 :003 > eval("$foo = 12")
 => 12 
2.6.3 :004 > $foo
 => 12
```

Although I might find some hacky way to deal with this situation, I'm sure you can see where I'd *really* rather not.

The Binding class offers methods to set local and instance vars dynamically within a Binding object, but nothing for globals (apparently). I've thought about something like this:

```rb
...
eval code_string, get_binding()
...

def get_binding
  $global = :special_value
  binding
end
```

but I'm really worried, with a Rails app that might be servicing lots of requests at the same time, that these settings of `$global` will step on each other in unpredictable ways. **Related clarifying question:** Is a global value in a Rails app global to the entire thing, readable and writable within the scope of all the requests whose servicing may be overlapping in time? (I'm running under Passenger, if that means anything)

So this is a fairly simple and straightforward problem when you understand it, although oddly not addressed in anything I can google about it, and I think I've written enough words. Thanks for any help or ideas to try.

**BIG EDIT:**

Ok, let me try to refocus this in a different way. I'm getting that the scope of a global can never, no-how, be constrained (duh, right?), but how about this strategy (similar to above):

```
...
eval code_string, get_binding()
...

def get_binding
  luaapg = :special_value  ## local used as a pseudo-global
  binding
end
```

So, now I've got this Binding that includes the local var `luaapg`. I've confirmed that. I eval `code_string` with this Binding. When I am somewhere inside the execution of `code_string`, *where do I find* `luaapg` - how do I access it? If you look at pretty much every tutorial on this stuff on the web, they show you `puts eval("luaapg", get_binding)` and voila, the assigned value comes out! But this is too simplistic for real life. When I am in the middle of my `code_string`, in some method scope of some class, `luaapg` is not there. I had great hope that this would work, even deep down the stack:

```
TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variable_get(:luaapg)
```

but it doesn't (I learned about TOPLEVEL_BINDING from [here](https://bparanj.gitbooks.io/ruby-basics/content/part2/binding.html) - thanks to that author). **So this is the new question:** what does it mean to say that I have executed (eval'ed) my code_string in the context of that Binding, which contains a local variable, if I have no way to access that variable, other than with the most simpleminded code? (incidentally I played around with instance vars too - same thing). I'm still hoping there's some magic incantation...

Comment: You can't make a global local, but you could use #dup or #clone to create a local copy of the value inside a block scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've put your finger on it in the name of the type of variable - it's global - common to all the code in the executing program.  I'm not sure exactly how Passenger works but I suspect it runs several copies of your program, so it won't be common between the copies.

To get reliable shared information I think you're going to have to use your database or some sort of information cache like memcached.  You choose how you save/name it there.